# iOS: Access inputAccessoryView for a textfield in a WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to change the tint color for text displayed in the toolbar above the iOS keyboard.

However the textfield is in an embedded WebView.

How can I access it?

Comment: There is no proper way to achieve this, you will need to use method swizzling. That can get your app banned from the App Store

Comment: This is extremely difficult, as the UIWebView first responder (which is the one which returns the inputAccessoryView) is a private class in a private view hierarchy.  You have to use a number of hairy tricks with the ObjC runtime to even make it possible, including creating a subclass at runtime.  I think it would be legal for the app store, but it's not for the faint of heart to maintain.  Other way is to rummage around the keyboard window's view hierarchy to find the view, but that is even more error-prone and does violate the app store terms, since that is all private.